Complex Step coefficients
Asking a very similar question to this one Finite differences coefficients. I was wondering if there existed a similar method for obtaining the coefficients of the complex step approximation. You can still build a linear system from the points and try to solve it for the coefficients; however, now the matrix can get singular, for example take the points $\{x_0 = x-h, x_1 = x+h\}$.
$$  \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -1 & 1\\
 \frac{1}{3!} & \frac{-1}{3!}\\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \alpha _0 \\
 \alpha _1
\end{array}
\right)  =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
I was wondering if there was a realibable method for obtaining the coefficients for an arbitrary set of points. I don't know if something like the Lagrange interpolation can be obtained for this.
